# geodjango with postgis would not work

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I am new to geodjango, I have the following settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default" : {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'dbname',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'django',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'somepass',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    "app.core",
)
```

and I have created the db with following command:

```
postgres@rewitaqia:~$ createdb -U postgres -T template_postgis -O django dbname
```

but when I try to sync the db it says:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot determine PostGIS version for database "dbname". GeoDjango requires at least PostGIS version 1.3. Was the database created from a spatial database template?
```

Also the when I try this in psql it seems that db tas not really created from postgis template:

```
db_name=# select postgis_lib_version();
ERROR:  no existe la función postgis_lib_version()
ŘÁDKA 1: select postgis_lib_version();
                ^
DOPORUČENÍ:  Ninguna función coincide en el nombre y tipos de argumentos. Puede desear agregar conversión explícita de tipos.
```

Thanks for reading anyway.

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the same database you `createdb`'d when you test with psql? Could there be two different ones with different case, *or one with and one without an underscore*? Connect with `psql` and run `\l` .

Comment: Does your database have the tables 'geometry_columns' and 'spatial_ref_sys'?

Comment: @RickyA: No it seems that it does not

Comment: @CraigRinger yes, they are same...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visgean,

When setting up PostGIS for the first time, I had a lot of the same questions as you so I created an article detailing the PostGIS setup.  Sorry to plug my own article, but I created it to help document the setup process. 
http://www.chicagodjango.com/blog/geo-django-quickstart/

Looking at your question above, it's hard to tell exactly what the issue is.  However, things you might check that would produce that PostGIS error listed:

- Are all the apt system dependencies are installed?  See Step 1 from the article.
- When you created the postgis_template schema, did run the commands to create the geospacial database objects (See Step 2 of attached link)?
- Is a fairly recent version of PostGIS installed?  Check the minimum requirements at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#spatial-database

Anyway, hope this helps.   Joe

Comment: Please help me with this, I have the same setting of this question but I got  error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "apple"` when I remove `'PASSWORD': 'somepass',` I got another error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`
-Also, How to get the current password?